# Putting taskbar position on TOP cuts off bottom of programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, desktop

So this is a very strange and fairly irritating issue I have with Windows 10. On my primary monitor, with the taskbar positioned on top; certain parts of my programs often get cut off and overflow beyond the screen.

The following screenshot illustrates my point:

[image: Can't see the scroll arrow]

In the above screenshot, I'm using Adobe Premiere and similar things happen with other programs whereby clickable areas / aspects of a program would essentially be 'unclickable' as they would overflow off the screen on the window with the taskbar.

However, if I enable 'Automatically Hide the Taskbar' in my taskbar options, the problem is fixed. So essentially **the taskbar is cutting off parts of my primary display's viewable area**.

Now you might be thinking, why don't I just that option or move the program to my second monitor. Well those are workarounds, but not a solution due to the way my workflow is structured.

Anyone know how I might fix this problem? It certainly does not occur when the taskbar is positioned at the bottom or sides :(

Comment: Is the Premiere window sized to fit that monitor when the taskbar is hidden? If it is, perhaps that is why it is hidden when you don't autohide the taskbar. Can you manually resize the Premiere window to accommodate?

Comment: @Dimblefeck - Manually resizing the Premiere window doesn't work. The selection dialog (as in the screenshot) still overflows